# Php add new headers to the current request

Tags: php, http-headers, owncloud

i have two methods:

method one catch the username and password

method 2 is a service that should catch the username and password through custom request headers

i want to add the username and password as custom headers to the current request so method 2 can handle them

method 2 has one parameter which is IRequest

i'm using OwnCloud, trying to make a plugin app to control Authentication, this works when calling OwnCloud through webdav in C# but i need it to control OwnCloud login page also by catching userName and password and use the same code in the module object

[image]

how can add new headers to the current request call since the header("..") function not working?

```
class Application extends App {
    public function pre_login($parameters) { // method 1

        $uid = $parameters['uid'];
        $password = $parameters['password'];

        header("UserId:" . $uid);
        header("Password:" . $password);

     }
}

class AuthModule implements IAuthModule {

    public function auth(IRequest $request) { // method 2
        $UserId = $request->getHeader('UserId'); // not working
        $password= $request->getHeader('password'); // not working
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: sorry, added the question

Comment: __Request__ is something that comes outside of your app. It's not your app's task to add __headers to request__. You can add headers to __response__ and send these headers to client. Client receives your response, extracts headers and can send these headers __back__ to your app as a part or request.

Comment: what framework are you using ? where does IRequest implementation come from ?

Comment: i'm using OwnCloud, trying to make a plugin app to control Authentication, this works when calling OwnCloud through webdav in C# but i need it to control OwnCloud login page also by catching userName and password and use the same code in the module object

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different apps and want to get headers (on your api for example) take into account that some frameworks add additional info to headers. Try getHeader('HTTP_UserId')